# Jest SpyOn - Actual Method is Called, Instead of the Mocked Implementation

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I've searched high and low to try and get my Jest test to work but have gotten nowhere in my search.

I've got a function (`createRoom`) that I want to unit test and I want to mock a method (`gameFactory.createNewGameWithInitialPlayer()`) call.

**GameService.ts**

```js
const GameService = (games: {[index: string]: Game}) => {
  const playerFactory = PlayerFactory()
  const gameFactory = new GameFactory()

  const createRoom = ({name, device, socketID}: {name: string, device: string, socketID: string}): RoomResponse => {
    const player = playerFactory.createNewPlayer(name, device, socketID)

    if (player && player.id) {
        const game: Game|undefined = gameFactory.createNewGameWithInitialPlayer(player)
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**GameFactory.ts**

```js
export class GameFactory {
    createNewGameWithInitialPlayer = (player: Player): Game|undefined => {
        const game = new Game()
        game.spectators[player.id as any as number] = player

        return game
    }
}
```

**GameService.test.ts**

```js
import * as gameFactory from '../Factories/GameFactory'

describe('Testing Game Service', () => {
    test('createRoom', () => {
        jest.spyOn(gameFactory, 'GameFactory').mockReturnValue({ createNewGameWithInitialPlayer: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(undefined)})

        const response: RoomResponse = gameService.createRoom({
            name: 'Player 1',
            device: DevicesEnum.ios,
            socketID: 'some-socket-id'
        })
    ...
    }
    ...
}
```

In `GameService.test.ts` I am mocking the return value of the `createNewGameWithInitialPlayer` method call. However, when I run the test, the *actual* implementation of it runs, instead of my mocked version. For this test in particular, I want the `createNewGameWithInitialPlayer` method to return `undefined`, but that does not happen, it appears to be calling the actual method implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to override the *createNewGameWithInitialPlayer* and return what you want then, you have to mock the import of **GameFactory** class in your test.

```
// Here you are creating your mock and saying the default return Game object
const mockCreateNewGameWithInitialPlayer = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => new Game());

// Here you say to jest that any file who wants to import "GameFactory"
// will import this fake class
jest.mock('rootofGameFactory/GameFactory', () => ({
    GameFactory: function(){
      return {
        // and when any file wants to execute this method, will execute my mock
        createNewGameWithInitialPlayer: mockCreateNewGameWithInitialPlayer
      }
    }
}))

describe('Testing Game Service', () => {
    test('createRoom', () => {
        const response: RoomResponse = gameService.createRoom({
            name: 'Player 1',
            device: DevicesEnum.ios,
            socketID: 'some-socket-id'
        })
    ...
    }
    ...
}
```

If you want to change the return object of your mocked method, you have to do it like this...

```
test('createRoom 2', () => {
        //Here you say to jest, just ONCE (for this test) return an instance of Game2
        mockCreateNewGameWithInitialPlayer.mockImplementationOnce(() => new Game2())
        const response: RoomResponse = gameService.createRoom({
            name: 'Player 1',
            device: DevicesEnum.ios,
            socketID: 'some-socket-id'
        })
    ...
    }
```

Comment: This did the trick! You don't know how much you've just helped me :). Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The [jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) mentions

> By default, jest.spyOn also calls the spied method. This is different behavior from most other test libraries. If you want to overwrite the original function, you can use jest.spyOn(object, methodName).mockImplementation(() => customImplementation) or jest.replaceProperty(object, methodName, jest.fn(() => customImplementation));

So you could do something like

```
jest.spyOn(gameFactory, 'GameFactory').mockImplementation(() => { return undefined })
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Julien. This unfortunately did not work for me. I am trying to mock only a function inside that `GameFactory` class, with this approach I got errors about that `return undefined`, it was expecting the function to be defined.